# Animate view resize

Tags: android, animation, layout, view

I need to dynamically resize central view, when keyboard (or another view) opens up from the bottom of the screen. I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` in manifest, bit it doesn't helps. When keyboard opens, view is cropped from top and bottom. I need to get it scaled like [on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI6OI.jpg).

It's name SnappingRecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f4f5f7">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#f4f5f7"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/camera59" />

            ...

        </RelativeLayout>

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.superup.smartshelf.view.SnappingRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/show_camera" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the activity of your manifest.

Comment: @user3549047 it doesn't help. view get's up and cropped from top and bottom

Comment: @user3549047 how to add animation on view scale when keyboard gets shown?